# Bar Button tint color in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

In iOS 13, they have changed the way that the nav bar colors operate. Now they use UINavigationBarAppearance along with UIBarButtonItemAppearance to customize the nav bar, along with standardAppearance & scrollEdgeAppearance.

I'm looking for a way to have different nav bar tint colors for standardAppearance & scrollEdgeAppearance. Or the ability to change bar button icon colors for each appearance.

```
        //set the standard nav bar appearance
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.mainAppColorForNavBar

        //set bar button appearance
        let buttonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
        buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
        navBarAppearance.buttonAppearance = buttonAppearance

        UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).standardAppearance = navBarAppearance



        //set the scroll edge nav bar appearance
        let scrollNavBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        scrollNavBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        scrollNavBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.label]
        scrollNavBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.label]

        //set bar button appearance
        let scrollButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
        scrollButtonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.label]
        scrollNavBarAppearance.buttonAppearance = scrollButtonAppearance

        UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationController.self]).scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollNavBarAppearance
```

This will set the nav bar tint color but does not distinguish between  standardAppearance & scrollEdgeAppearance.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

currently in scrollEdgeAppearance (looks the way I want, no changes needed)
[image]

currently in standardAppearance (the button is lost because it's the same color as the background, I want to change the icon color to white in standardAppearance )
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @Mohammadalijf Sorry for the delay, no solution found yet.

Comment: @user1184205 any solution?

Comment: @JERC Sorry man, not that I have found.  I ended up changing the color of the button so it would stick out in both states.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue for the back button and solved it with setting an image with a different rendering mode for each appearance. This avoids a tintColor being applied.

```
// demo image
let image = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")!

// image with .alwaysOriginal rendering mode to avoid tintColor application
let imageForNavBarAppearance = image
    .withTintColor(.black)
    .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
let imageForScrollNavBarAppearance = image
    .withTintColor(.green)
    .withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

// your UINavigationBarAppearance instances
navBarAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(imageForNavBarAppearance, transitionMaskImage: imageForNavBarAppearance)
scrollNavBarAppearance.setBackIndicatorImage(imageForScrollNavBarAppearance, transitionMaskImage: imageForScrollNavBarAppearance)
```

This solves it for back buttons only.

There are two other options to set background images for bar item appearances.

`UINavigationBarAppearance.buttonAppearance`
The appearance configuration with the background image would be applied to all bar items.
This should be fine, since you only have one bar item.

`UINavigationBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance`
If you'd create a done-style bar item for your top-right "+" symbol, this appearance configuration should apply.

```
let ap = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
ap.normal.backgroundImage = image.withTintColor(.black).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

let scrollAp = UIBarButtonItemAppearance()
scrollAp.normal.backgroundImage = image.withTintColor(.green).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

// apply to all bar items
navBarAppearance.buttonAppearance = ap
scrollNavBarAppearance.buttonAppearance = scrollAp

// or apply to done buttons
navBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance = ap
scrollNavBarAppearance.doneButtonAppearance = scrollAp
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with iOS 13 `UINavigationBarAppearance` , `UIBarButtonItemAppearance` etc. I realised that setting a color to `navigationBar.tintColor` directly apparenty overrides any `UIBarButtonItemAppearance` configurations.

So here is my workaround:

Given that your UIViewController most likely uses an UICollectionView, UITableView, UIScrollView use it’s `UIScrollViewDelegate` to get scroll updates. Also possible via KVO:

```swift
private func observeScrollView() {
    self.observer = scrollView.observe(
        \UIScrollView.contentOffset,
        options: .new
    ) { [weak self] scrollView, change in
        guard let offsetY = change.newValue?.y else { return  }
       self?.handleScroll(offsetY)
    }
}
```

Now you need to calculate if your LargeTitles are still showing. You can use navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY to access it’s height.

```swift
private func handleScroll(_ offsetY: CGFloat) {
    let offsetY = -offsetY

    let threshold: CGFloat = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY ?? 88
    let largeTitlesVisible = offsetY > threshold
    self.largeTitlesVisible = largeTitlesVisible
}
```

Use property observers to catch toggles.

```swift
private var largeTitlesVisible: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != largeTitlesVisible {
            updateNavbar(tranparent: largeTitlesVisible)
       }
    }
}
```

Now actually change the navbars appearance:

```swift
func updateNavbar(transparent: Bool) {
    // overrides UIBarButtonItemAppearance, UINavigationBarAppearance configurations ...
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = transparent ? UIColor.clear : UIColor.systemGreen
}
```